# Pandas Tail - index 0 is out of bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am receiving an "index 0 is out of bounds" error using the code below. I have exhausted my options to debug on my own and would really appreciate some help om solving this issue. Thank you!

**Data:**

```
game_info.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 30362 entries, 0 to 30361
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------         --------------  -----         
 0   competitionId  30362 non-null  Int64         
 1   gameId         30349 non-null  Int64         
 2   gameDate       30362 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 3   gameTime       30362 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 4   awayId         30362 non-null  int64         
 5   homeId         30362 non-null  int64         
 6   awayScore      30362 non-null  int64         
 7   homeScore      30362 non-null  int64         
 8   homeWin        29889 non-null  Int64         
 9   homePush       30362 non-null  Int64         
dtypes: Int64(4), datetime64[ns](2), int64(4)
memory usage: 2.4 MB
```

```
game_info.head()
```

|  | competitionId | gameId | gameDate | gameTime | awayId | homeId | awayScore | homeScore | homeWin | homePush |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021 | 4584762 | 2022-01-20 | 2022-01-20 20:00:00 | 765 | 829 | 75 | 56 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021 | 4586420 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-08 15:00:00 | 823 | 677 | 68 | 66 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2018 | 3642155 | 2019-01-24 | 2019-01-24 18:00:00 | 1374 | 670 | 70 | 88 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021 | 4611286 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-10 19:30:00 | 825 | 824 | 58 | 95 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2022 | 4678182 | 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-29 19:00:00 | 1099 | 824 | 54 | 92 | 1 | 0 |

**Code:**

```
# get expected win prob for home team 
def get_home_E(homeElo, awayElo): 
    home_win_prob = 1./(1 + 10 ** ((awayElo - homeElo) / (400)))
    return home_win_prob

# get multiplier K 
def get_k(MOV, elo_diff): 
    k_initial = 20 
    if MOV > 0: 
        multiplier = (MOV + 3)**0.8 / (7.5 + 0.006 * (elo_diff))
    else: 
        multiplier = (-MOV + 3)**0.8 / (7.5 + 0.006 * (-elo_diff))
    return k_initial * multiplier 

# update home elo and away elo 
def update_elo(homeScore, awayScore, homeEloPrev, awayEloPrev):
    home_adv = 100 
    homeElo = homeEloPrev + home_adv 
    home_E = get_home_E(homeElo, awayEloPrev) 
    # away_E = 1 - home_E
    elo_diff = homeEloPrev - awayEloPrev
    MOV = homeScore - awayScore 
    if (MOV > 0) :
        home_S = 1 
    elif (MOV < 0):
        home_S= 0 
    else: 
        home_S = 0.5 
    
    k = get_k(MOV, elo_diff)
    home_elo_update = k * (home_S - home_E) 

    updated_home_elo = homeEloPrev + home_elo_update
    updated_away_elo = awayEloPrev - home_elo_update

    return updated_home_elo, updated_away_elo

# get the team elo after the previous game 
def get_prev_elo(teamId, gameTime, competitionId, game_info, elo_per_game): 
    prev_game = game_info[game_info['gameTime'] < gameTime][((game_info['homeId'] == teamId) | (game_info['awayId'] == teamId)) & (game_info['gameId'] != gameId)].tail(1).iloc[0]
    if teamId == prev_game['homeId'] :
        elo_rating = elo_per_game[elo_per_game['gameId'] == prev_game['gameId']]['homeEloAfter'].values[0]
    else:
        elo_rating = elo_per_game[elo_per_game['gameId'] == prev_game['gameId']]['awayEloAfter'].values[0]

    if prev_game['competitionId'] != competitionId :
        return (0.75 * elo_rating) + (0.25 * 1505)
    else:
        return elo_rating
```

```
# save elo result for every game to elo_per_team, for every team to elo_per_team
elo_per_game = pd.DataFrame(columns=['competitionId', 'gameId', 'gameDate', 'homeId', 'awayId', 'homeEloPrev', 'awayEloPrev', 'homeEloAfter', 'awayEloAfter'])
elo_per_team = pd.DataFrame(columns=['competitionId', 'gameId', 'gameDate', 'teamId', 'elo', 'home']) 
for index, row in game_info.iterrows():
    # grab constants
    gameId = row['gameId'] 
    competitionId = row['competitionId']
    gameDate = row['gameDate'] 
    gameTime = row['gameTime'] 
    homeId, awayId = int(row['homeId']), int(row['awayId'])
    homeScore, awayScore = row['homeScore'], row['awayScore']
    
    # grab home teams previous ELO (1500 if first game)
    if (homeId not in elo_per_game['homeId'].values and homeId not in elo_per_game['awayId'].values): 
        homeEloPrev = 1500
    else: 
        homeEloPrev = get_prev_elo(homeId, gameTime, competitionId, game_info, elo_per_game)
        
    # grab away teams previous ELO (1500 if first game) 
    if (awayId not in elo_per_game['homeId'].values and awayId not in elo_per_game['awayId'].values): 
        awayEloPrev = 1500 
    else: 
        awayEloPrev = get_prev_elo(awayId, gameTime, competitionId, game_info, elo_per_game)
    
    # update elo ratings for this game
    homeEloAfter, awayEloAfter = update_elo(homeScore, awayScore, homeEloPrev, awayEloPrev) 

    # create new rows to add to elo_per_game, elo_per_team
    # elo_per_game (1 row per game, adding team's post-game elo to this)
    # elo_per_team (1 row per team-game, updating team's ELO over time)
    updated_row = {
        'gameId': gameId,
        'competitionId': competitionId,
        'gameDate': gameDate,
        'homeId': homeId,
        'awayId': awayId,
        'homeEloPrev': homeEloPrev,
        'awayEloPrev': awayEloPrev, 
        'homeEloAfter' : homeEloAfter,
        'awayEloAfter': awayEloAfter
    }
    elo_per_game = elo_per_game.append(updated_row, ignore_index = True)

    homeTeam = {'gameId': gameId, 'competitionId': competitionId, 'gameDate': gameDate, 'teamId': homeId, 'elo': homeEloPrev, 'home': True}
    awayTeam = {'gameId': gameId, 'competitionId': competitionId, 'gameDate': gameDate, 'teamId': awayId, 'elo': awayEloPrev, 'home': False}
    elo_per_team = elo_per_team.append(homeTeam, ignore_index = True)
    elo_per_team = elo_per_team.append(awayTeam, ignore_index = True)
    
    # print logging every 2000 rows processed
    if index % 4000 == 0:
        print(index)
    
    # can add EloPrev and EloAfter directly to game_info table
```

**Error:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[713], line 17
     15     homeEloPrev = 1500
     16 else: 
---> 17     homeEloPrev = get_prev_elo(homeId, gameTime, competitionId, game_info, elo_per_game)
     19 # grab away teams previous ELO (1500 if first game) 
     20 if (awayId not in elo_per_game['homeId'].values and awayId not in elo_per_game['awayId'].values): 

Cell In[712], line 44, in get_prev_elo(teamId, gameTime, competitionId, game_info, elo_per_game)
     42     elo_rating = elo_per_game[elo_per_game['gameId'] == prev_game['gameId']]['homeEloAfter'].values[0]
     43 else:
---> 44     elo_rating = elo_per_game[elo_per_game['gameId'] == prev_game['gameId']]['awayEloAfter'].values[0]
     46 if prev_game['competitionId'] != competitionId :
     47     return (0.75 * elo_rating) + (0.25 * 1505)

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions that the values result is empty (size 0), therefore you cannot get it's 0 index.

Try debugging your code to see why would this happen (empty result).

If it's supposed to be empty-
Check the len of the values before using [0].

```
if len(...values) == 0:
    Do something
else:
    Do something else
```

You may also use "try, except" but it is better to find another approach (such as the "if" statement)

Please add more information if this answer didn't solve your issue.